# Why does this Ruby case statement return "can't convert nil into String (TypeError)" when used with ||?

Tags: ruby, syntax, case-statement

I originally had this code written as a series of `if` statements, but after learning more about Ruby decided a `case` statement might be more appropriate. However, now it seems to be broken and I'm not sure why.

```
location = gets.chomp.downcase

case location
when 'v' || 'vaca'
  file1, file2 = 'vMasterLocation.csv', 'vMasterSR.csv'
when 'c' || 'comm'
  file1, file2 = 'cMasterLocation.csv', 'cMasterSR.csv'
else
  puts "Not a valid location."
  exit
end
```

The statement runs as expected when `location`'s input is either `V`, `v`, `C`, or `c`, but whenever I try inputting `vaca` or `comm` Ruby return the following: `csv.rb:1335:in 'initialize': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)`

Am I using `||` incorrectly or maybe I misunderstood case statements? Any feedback is much appreciated. Thanks!

Here it is in its previous form as an `if` statement just for reference:

```
location = gets.chomp.downcase
if location == 'v' || location == 'vaca'
  file1, file2 = 'vMasterLocation.csv', 'vMasterSR.csv'
elsif location == 'c' || location == 'comm'
  file1, file2 = 'cMasterLocation.csv', 'cMasterSR.csv'
else
  puts "Not a valid location."
  exit
end
```

Also, is this a proper 'Ruby' use of the `case` statement over the `if` statement? I'm trying to figure out when it is more appropriate to use one over the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a comma rather than `||`:

```
case location
when 'v', 'vaca'
```

See [here](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#case) for more on the syntax of case statements.

Comment: Can you explain why `||` doesn't work with `case` statements? I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that they use `===` for comparisons, but I don't understand how that makes `||` not work. Thank you!

Comment: The part after `||` will just never be executed (because `when 'v'` doesn't evaluate to `false`) - you can see this for yourself: `when 'v' || raise("You'll never see this")`

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
location = gets.chomp.downcase

case location
when 'v', 'vaca'
  file1, file2 = 'vMasterLocation.csv', 'vMasterSR.csv'
when 'c', 'comm'
  file1, file2 = 'cMasterLocation.csv', 'cMasterSR.csv'
else
  puts "Not a valid location."
  exit
end
```